# std::function vs callable as template parameter

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, std-function, template-argument-deduction, stdapply

In the example below, why line 20 causes the error described from line 27 to 30?

Calling `exec1` in line 33 works fine.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... t_fields>
void exec0(std::function<std::tuple<t_fields...>()> generate,
           std::function<void(t_fields &&...)> handle) {
  std::tuple<t_fields...> _tuple{generate()};
  std::apply(handle, std::move(_tuple));
}

template <typename t_generate, typename t_function>
void exec1(t_generate generate, t_function handle) {
  auto _tuple{generate()};
  std::apply(handle, std::move(_tuple));
}

int main() {
  auto _h = [](uint32_t u) -> void { std::cout << "u = " << u << '\n'; };

  auto _g = []() -> std::tuple<uint32_t> { return std::tuple<uint32_t>{456}; };

  //  exec0<uint32_t>(_g, _h);
  /*
main.cpp:25:3: error: no matching function for call to 'exec0'
main.cpp:8:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
'function<tuple<unsigned int, type-parameter-0-0...> ()>' against '(lambda at
/var/tmp/untitled002/main.cpp:23:13)'
  */

  exec1(_g, _h);

  return 0;
}
```

`g++ --version` replies:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Always post **code that does not work**. Never code that does not work if you uncomment a line here and change a line there.

Comment: I was trying to show the cases that work and do not work, to help anyone to understand my question, and therefore help to have it answered.

Comment: Comment out code that works then,

Comment: I agree, it's slightly better to have the code in a broken state by default. You can point at the problematic lines with comments. It saves a few seconds of trying to understand what you need to uncomment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you specified `<uint32_t>` as a template argument, the compiler seems to try to deduce more elements for the parameter pack, fails to do so (because the type of a lambda is not `std::function<...>`), and becomes upset.

You need to somehow inhibit template argument deduction.

Either call it as `exec0<uint32_t>({_g}, {_h});`, or wrap parameter types in `std::type_identity_t<...>` (or, pre-C++20, `std::enable_if_t<true, ...>`).

Then the compiler will accept your `uint32_t` as the only type in the pack, and won't try to add more types.